# how to make selection of input file in ADF mobile framework

Tags: oracle-adf, oracle-maf

i am making the MAF application for practice but in this application am giving the functionality of upload and download files from server and but input file component is not giving in the ORACLE MAF and am successfully done the upload button but i am not know how to add input select file component in the MAF. please
help me .
thank you

please answer this question...

Answer (score 0):

For download, you can use this tag into an amx page :

```
<amx:goLink text="Download" id="bla" url="http://www.yourservlet.com/download"/>
```

For the upload functionality, I am not sure if that works somehow. Try to follow up [this question](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3875810?start=0&tstart=0) of the Oracle Community to find out more about the upload functionality.

Hope to be helpful.
Thanks.